# Click on item leads to IllegalStateException

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, illegalstateexception

How can this happen? I use a `RecyclerView` in an fragment and the fragment itself implements my click listener...

Sometimes, clicking an item in the list results in following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
```

*How can this happen? Clicks should be forwarded to their handlers synchronous and this should not happen, should it?*

Comment: Do you have some code?

Comment: I don't know what to post. It's really rare and above is just an example... It happens in libraries like the MaterialDialog library, it happens in VERY simple fragments, when I click a button... I have 10 thousands of users and such a bug only occurs about every 5 days or so...

Answer (score 0):

Some code fragment would really help. But your error already states `Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState`

This means that after the function `onSaveInstanceState()` has been called, you try to do something. Put that code before `onSaveInstanceState()` and you **might** have a solution.

Comment: OnSaveInstanceState is part of the life cycle. A button click is a result from an event while the fragment is started and a button click should be handled synchronous, therefore it should never make a problem with onSaveInstanceState...

Comment: Yes, it is part of the life cycle and is called just before onDestroy() in order to save any unfinished work if needed. As you said, it should never make a problem, which has been the case for me. If you edit your question and add some code, then maybe I (or someone else) might see the issue.

Comment: actually, I don't know what code to post... read my comment under my main question... this happens once in a while and actually, I want to know if I can be 100% sure, that if I click a button, EVERYTHING in the button click handler will be executed before pausing, destroying and saving the fragment and that it MUST be a bug in my code...

Comment: Well, add the code about the combination of one button and one class from which this error suddenly gets displayed. Personally, I'd assume a bug in my code. The only issue that I have ever encountered that were (and still is) a real android bug, is setting a Boolean preference to false for it's initialization. (It doesn't get created unless it's set to true, so the preference always returned null.) But even for that bug, there was a work-around.

Answer (score 0):

OnSaveInstance is called when the activity is about to be destroyed.

The android gives a last attempt to save all the data in a bundle that can be retrived back when the activity is recreated onRestoreInstance.

Mostly this case occurs when the android decide to garbage collect your activity due to lack of memory.

The error state that you are doing some work on UI -fragment after the onSaveInstance has been called.

Android does not allow any work on fragments after this has been called and soon onDestroy will be called.

So kindly revisit your logic or place a isFinishing() check before doing any work.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's because you're activity is getting destroyed due to lack of memory and before it gets destroyed it saves the fragment state also, and like you mentioned it happens sometine, during this you might have clicked your own which tried calling that previous state non click on the destroyed fragment. 
How can you avoid it
Use volley and Picasso. And check which part of your application is using more memory using memory monitor given in android studio.
Also if you are not able to reduce memory usage consider adding.

large heap="true"

in your manifest